Does the photoURL property of FIrebase Auth user object update in realtime over multiple devices?
I have developed an app in Flutter with Firebase auth. I store profile images for each user in Firebase Storage. The 'photoURL' property of the user object points to an image from Firebase Storage uploaded by a user, which is then displayed on the profile page. The issue is that when I sign in as the same user on two devices and update the profile picture on one device, it DOES NOT get updated on the second device. I have to sign out and then sign in again for it to be updated.
Why is it not getting updated in real-time? Do I have to store photoURL in a Firestore database and update it from there? Or is there any other issue with the way I'm implementing this? Because the user object's photoURL property should get updated in real-time. Here's the code for the profile pic fetching and uploading:
Function to update photoURL of user object:
Future<void> updateUserProfile(String imageUrl) async {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      final currentDisplayName = user.displayName;
      await user.updateProfile(photoURL: imageUrl, displayName: currentDisplayName);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

The button that updates the profile picture:
ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final image = await pickImage(context);
                if (image != null) {
                  final croppedImage = await cropImage(image);
                  final croppedXFile = XFile(croppedImage!.path);
                  final imageUrl = await uploadImage(croppedXFile);
                  await Provider.of<ApplicationState>(context, listen: false).updateUserProfile(imageUrl);
                }
              },
              child: Text(
                photoURL!= null ? 'Change Profile Picture' : 'Upload Profile Picture',
              ),
            ),

Fetching and displaying profile picture:
FutureBuilder<User?>(
              future: Provider.of<ApplicationState>(context).authStateChanges.first,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  print(snapshot.error);
                  return const Text('Error loading user data');
                }
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final user = snapshot.data!;
                  final photoURL = user.photoURL;
                  if (photoURL != null) {
                    return ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(75),
                      child: Image.network(
                        photoURL,
                        width: 150,
                        height: 150,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return const Icon(Icons.person, size: 100);
                  }
                }
              },
            ),



I store profile images for each user in Firebase Storage.

That's a common approach. Cloud Storage for Firebase is a Firebase product that is designed to store files.

The photoURL property of the user object points to an image from Firebase Storage uploaded by a user, which is then displayed on the profile page.

Yes, that is the purpose of the photoURL property, to hold the URL of an image that exists in a Firebase Storage location or a URL of an image provided by a third-party OAuth provider, such as Google.

The issue is that when I sign in as the same user on two devices and update the profile picture on one device, it DOES NOT get updated on the second device. I have to sign out and then sign in again for it to be updated.

That's the expected behavior because other devices do not know what is happening on the other devices unless you sign out and then sign in again, to get fresh data. The is no real-time listener for things that are changing inside the User object. There is indeed a authStateChanges() which:

Notifies about changes to the user's sign-in state (such as sign-in or sign-out).

But it doesn't notify if the value of the photoURL property has changed.

Why is it not getting updated in real-time?

Because there is no listener that does that.

Do I have to store photoURL in a Firestore database and update it from there?

Yes, that is indeed a solution. You can add the value of photoURL property in a document in Firestore and listen for real-time updates.

okay then how is the profile picture getting updated on the same device if I'm still using authStateChanges() in that function to display profile pic after update?

The user.updateProfile() operation is asynchronous. This means that as soon as the operation is complete, the new photoURL that was updated becomes the new photo URL of the user and you can use it to display the image in your widget. Or you can write it to Firestore and use it as soon as the operation of writing the URL is complete, and then display the image in the widget.
